# Chkrootkit findings - what to do?

Tags: antivirus, viruses, malware, rootkit

after my ubuntu runs slower and slower and google regularly asks me for prooving to be human, i had Chkrootkit running. here's what it found:

```
wlan0: PACKET SNIFFER 
(/sbin/wpa_supplicant [870], 
/sbin/dhvlient [1237])
Searching for suspicious files and dirs, it may take a while … the  following suspicious files and directoris were found: 
/usr/lib/jvm/.java-1.6.0-openjdk-i386.jinfo
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/widget-plugins/.noinit
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/.path
```

since i have no idea what to do with this: what do i do with this?
thnx for responding,

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this on my laptop, here's how to fix it. Open a terminal and run the following command:

```
cd && mkdir WPA && cd WPA && apt-get download wpa-supplicant
```

Now, open your favorite file-manager (thunar, nautilus, dolphin, etc...) using sudo in the WPA directory like this:

```
sudo nautilus ~/WPA
```

Next, right-click on the deb file and select the option "extract here" then,

right-click on the newly extracted archive and select "rename".

Name the file "NEW"

Now, open a terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo cp /sbin/wpa_supplicant ~/WPA/wpacopy
sudo rm /sbin/wpa_supplicant
sudo cp ~/WPA/NEW/sbin/wpa_supplicant /sbin/wpa_supplicant
sudo chmod +x /sbin/wpa_supplicant
sudo chmod 600 ~/WPA/wpacopy
sudo service network-manager restart
```

And to verify this worked, run:

```
sudo chkrootkit
```

The output should say something about the "SNIFFER" being deleted, moved, or may even indicate where the sniffer was moved to ( ~/WPA/wpacopy ).